# Iterate through grid headers not rendered in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, jasmine, protractor

I need to check if grid contains all specified headers, but not all headers are visible in DOM in the same time, so I have to scroll to 'discover' more headers, but I don't really know how to get it working because of asynchronous nature of javascript.

I tried something like this, but I don't think this is a good approach.

```
var self = this;

  this.checkGridHeaders = function(gridName, expectedHeaders) {

    var previous;
    var headers = this.poGridUtil.getGrid( gridName ).element( by.css('.ui-grid-render-container-body'))
        .element( by.css('.ui-grid-header') ).all( by.repeater('col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid') );

    headers.each(function(header, headerIndex) {
          if(expectedHeaders.length != 0 && header != 'undefined')  {
            header.getText().then(function(headerText){
              if(headerText == '') {
                browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", previous).then(function() {
                  self.checkGridHeaders(expectedHeaders);
                });
              }

              previous = header;
              console.log('***Element: ' + headerText );
              expect(expectedHeaders.indexOf(headerText)).not.toEqual(-1);
              header = 'undefined';
            });
          }
    });
  };
```

and call looks like this: `checkGridHeaders('grid-className', ['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4']);`

Basically I want to check if `expectedHeader` is visible and if not then scroll to last known header and then check again. I just don't know how to properly write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It is not the best approach, but works.

```
  this.checkGridHeaders = function(gridName, expectedHeaders, iterationNumber) {
    if(isNaN(iterationNumber))
        iterationNumber = 5;

    var headers = [];

    var findHeaders = function() {
      return self.poGridUtil.getGrid( gridName ).element( by.css('.ui-grid-render-container-body .ui-grid-header'))
         .all( by.repeater('col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid')).then(function (foundHeaders) {
           var next = foundHeaders[foundHeaders.length - 1];
           return self.getResolvedText(foundHeaders).then(function(result) {
              browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", next.getWebElement());

              for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                  var cut = result[i].toString().replace("\n", "");
                  var shorten = cut.trim();
                  if(shorten !== "" && shorten !== " ")
                    headers.push(shorten);
              }

              browser.sleep(500);
              return result;
           });
         });
    };

    var headerFinders = [];
    for (var iterIndex = 0; iterIndex < iterationNumber; iterIndex++)
        headerFinders.push(findHeaders());

    var allPromises = headerFinders.map(function(item) {
      return item;
    });

    var finderResult = protractor.promise.all(allPromises).then(function(presentValues) {
      return presentValues;
    });

    finderResult.then(function(resultItems) {
      var newHeaders = headers.filter( function( item, index, inputArray ) {
        return inputArray.indexOf(item) == index;
      });
      for(var index = 0; index < expectedHeaders.length; index++) {
        expect(newHeaders).toContain(expectedHeaders[index], 'Nie znaleziono naglowka: ' + expectedHeaders[index]);
      }
    });
  };
```

If anyone knows how to tidy up this code, feel free to post a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
 var self = this;

 this.checkGridHeaders = function(gridName, expectedHeaders) {
    var defer = protractor.promise.defer();
    this.poGridUtil.getGrid( gridName ).element( by.css('.ui-grid-render-container-body .ui-grid-header'))
    .all( by.repeater('col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid')).then(function (headers) {
         var headerText =[];
         for(var i=0;i<headers.length;i++){
             browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", headers[i].getWebElement())
             headerText.push(headers[i].getText())
         }
        defer.fulfill(headerText);
    })
    expect(defer.promise()).toContain(expectedHeaders)
   });
 };
```

Comment: it throws: `defer.promise is not a function` in `expect(defer.promise()).toContain(expectedHeaders);`. Also you used too many brackets between `expect(defer.promise()).toContain(expectedHeaders)`

Comment: I fixed the previous error, but now it scrolls to each column very fast and throws: `A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.`

Comment: The problem with this is it starts iterating by number of columns found in the beginning and this is exactly my problem, because in the beginning I don't know the count of columns, because a couple of them are not visible in DOM. So for example `headers.length` is 10 even though the real number is 13... I need something that checks if there is a new column each time it scrolls.